# How to ignore the hash '#' symbol in Python?

Tags: python, syntax

I have a python code that makes a POST Request. 
As authentication parameters, I am passing username and password in the call. 
My password contains a hash '#' symbol in it, which my IDE keeps mistaking it for when a comment is written in python.

See the example below:

```
     response = requests.post(url,
                             json={ "group" : ["abc"] },
                             auth=('admin', 'myP#word'))
```

How do I make Python ignore the hash symbol so it doesn't ignore it by mistaking it for a comment?

Comment: I think that there is something wrong with your editor.  Because a hash (`#`) in a string is perfectly allowed. Furthermore mind that **communicating a password is a very bad idea**.

Comment: True, but you could try "\#", as usual.

Comment: What do you mean commented out? Does the server not receive it? Or is it a problem with your text editor not displaying it as you'd like?

Comment: it as a ide problem. got it working now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, `'myP#word'` does not have any problem at all.  Perhaps your editor or IDE is graying out the `#word` part, but Python considers it part of the string.  Try running the code and see.